# Can we use by the way after the new mentioned sentence?

Tags: grammar, informal-language

I met my friend in school

I asked him 'Why were you ignoring me on instagram'

He said 'I was not. It's just that my internet wasn't working'

I replied

No, you had seen my message and I'm not using instagram now, by the way

Can i use by the way this way

Wont it leave the listener in doubt?

By the way what?

Or should i say it this way

No you had seen my message
 ,by the way, I'm not using snapchat now

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're looking for "anyway" instead of "by the way." If you use "anyway" in your conversation, you will communicate to the listener that you are done talking about being ignored and that you are ready to move on to another topic. That should eliminate the issue of doubt. If you use "by the way," as you have it above, you are interjecting the information about not using instagram, but you are not acknowledging that you are ready to move on from being ignored by your friend.

> anyway - used to end a conversation, to change the subject, or to
>   resume a subject after interruption.

vs.

> by the way - incidentally (used to introduce a minor topic not
>   connected with what was being spoken about previously).

Comment: Excellent answer. I would amend "anyway" to include "regardless," though. "She knew it to be a wise choice far in advance, but decided to carry on with the plan anyway."